# How can I set timezone in NodeJs project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

When I send date from angular app to nodejs, it automatically changes. I have temporarily fixed it with:

`var fromdt = new Date(req.body.BIDInstalledFrom.toLocaleString("en-ind",{timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata'}));`

This allowed me to store datetime in my database as I had sent it from angular app.

But when I fetch the data from database with nodejs and send it to angular. Nodejs again converts it to some other timezone. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you need this for mysql date and time

Comment: I have postgres and column type is timestamp without timezone. 
I dont think there is an issue with database

Comment: then why do you need this in nodeJS.. you have moment js in angular js to convert date and time to convert timestamp according to timezon